# Using TO_NUMBER to parse numbers both in fixed notation and scientific notation

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, number-formatting, string-parsing

Using Oracle SQL, how can I convert string to a number when the string (a VARCHAR2 column) can contain either:

- a number in fixed notation, such as `-11.496606820938826`

  ```
  SELECT TO_NUMBER('-11.496606820938826', '999.999999999999999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''. ''') FROM DUAL;
  ```
- a number in scientific notation, such as `-4.0504035245989348E-3`

  ```
  SELECT TO_NUMBER('-4.0504035245989348E-3', '999.999999999999999999EEEE', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''. ''') FROM DUAL;
  ```

So far, I have used the following [format models](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211):

- Fixed notation: `999.999999999999999999`
- Scientific notation: `999.999999999999999999EEEE`

but I can't find a single format model which works is both cases.

Example data:

```
 STRING_VALUE
------------------------
 -4.0504035245989348E-3 
 -11.496606820938826    
------------------------
```

I am using Oracle 12.1, so I can't use either [VALIDATE_CONVERSION](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html) nor [ON CONVERSION ERROR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_NUMBER.html).

**Edit**

Moreover, this code is going to run on different enviroments with different NLS settings; I can't assume that using [`TO_NUMBER`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions227.htm#SQLRF06140) without a format model would just work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a `CASE` statement?

```
CREATE TABLE t (v VARCHAR2(30));
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('-11.49660682093882');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('-4.0504035245989348E-3');

SELECT v, CASE WHEN v LIKE '%E%' 
           THEN TO_NUMBER(v, '999.999999999999999999EEEE', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''. ''')
           ELSE TO_NUMBER(v, '999.999999999999999999',     'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''. ''') 
          END AS x
  FROM t;

V                        X
-11.49660682093882       -11,49660682093882
-4.0504035245989348E-3   -0,0040504035245989348
```